# Arranging Columns in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, multiple-columns

I need three columns of col3 size each in a row. I also need they be separated by at least the size of col2. That is, the first and third columns must be set to the left and right of the container respectively and the middle one will have equal margins on both sides.

How can this be achieved in Bootstrap latest version?

Comment: This is a complex enough question that you should be posting some code from an attempt on your part. I'd likely start with a `.pull-left` and `.pull-right` without a `.container`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use (with or without `.container`) :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-left col-xs-12 col-md-3">LEFT</div>
  <div class="col-center col-xs-12 col-md-3">CENTER</div>
  <div class="col-right col-xs-12 col-md-3">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

With a custom CSS to make it work :

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-left {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -12.5%;
  }
  .col-right {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/115488)

Comment: Thank you for the answers. When the screen sizes reduce, offsetting the middle column may create problems. The same problem happens with applying 50% left also. I need a solution for all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Standard Bootstrap builds are a 12 column setup. With 3 col-XX-3 and and col-XX-offset-2 that adds up to 13 columns (3+2+3+2+3=13). You would need to create a custom bootstrap build with 13 columns.

To achieve your desired look use the `col-XX-offset-*` where `XX` is the screen size (lg, md, sm, xs) and the `*` is the amount of offset. `col-XX-offset-*` offsets the column the `*` amount to the right.

So to get the look you want your code would look like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" style="background: #333; height:250px;"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2" style="background: #666; height:250px;"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2" style="background: #999; height:250px;"></div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Again this will not work for you unless you have your columns and offsets add up to 12. To make a custom Bootstrap 13 column build follow these steps:

1. Go here http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system
2. Change `@grid-columns` to 13
3. Scroll to the bottom of the page and click 'Compile and Download'
4. Replace old .css and .js with newly downloaded files.

I hope this helps. This is the best way to get the desired look and ensure that there is always a 2 column offset between your content columns.

*Note: You can remove the `style` attributes from the `col-md-3` divs. They were just there so the columns could be seen.*